# Dockerfile overriding ENV variable defined in parent Docker image

Tags: bash, docker, variables, environment

I'd like to create a "patch" image that updates a previous version Docker image with a few packages and updates the NO_PROXY environment variable.

I attempted to do this using a simple:

`ENV no_proxy=newurls.com`

line at the top of the file after the `FROM` statement.

But after launching a bash session in the newly created image and grepping env, I still see the old value of `no_proxy`.  What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:
Per the comments below, I decided to rebuild the parent image with my `no_proxy` settings:

`ENV no_proxy "vtgclearml.xyz.com,.xyz.com,localhost,127.0.0.1"`

But after starting this container, all I get is:

```
echo $no_proxy
.xyz.com
```

Could this be related to using the wildcard domain `.xyz.com` (the real domain is intentionally obfuscated)?

Using this variable definition from bash inside the container works just fine:

```
export no_proxy="vtgclearml.xyz.com,.xyz.com,localhost,127.0.0.1"
echo $no_proxy
vtgclearml.xyz.com,.xyz.com,localhost,127.0.0.1
```

As it turns out, I actually need the explicit vtgclearml.xyz.com domain, because otherwise my company proxy blocks ClearML.

Comment: I can't reproduce. I have an ubuntu image (`FROM ubuntu ENV no_proxy="something"`) that I built to `img1`. When I create another image (`FROM img1 ENV no_proxy="override"`), and I run `env` in a container with that last image, I can see `no_proxy=override`.

Comment: Oh, maybe there is an entrypoint that sets this variable when the container is created? What base image are you using? Can you provide your previous version Docker image's `Dockerfile`?

Comment: I'm pretty baffled... I tried setting the following in the "parent" Docker file:

```ENV no_proxy "vtgclearml.xyz.com,.xyz.com,localhost,127.0.0.1"```

But when I load up the container, all I get is:

```echo $NO_PROXY
.xyz.com```

Comment: Looks like something is overwriting what you set in your `Dockerfile`. Does your image have an entrypoint? Is something (a script) changing your env vars during the build?

Comment: @norbjd, I tried looking all over for something that does this, but couldn't.  It seems that ```.xyz.com``` gets automatically expanded to *.xyz.com which overrides all specific subdomains.  Eventually, I gave up and added an explicit ```-e no_proxy="..."``` in the call to ```docker run```.  Not really a solution, but gets the job done for now.